# Compare strings in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file named `parameters.txt` whose contents are as follows:

```
sheet_name:TEST
sheet_id:CST
sheet_access:YES
```

And I have a shell script which fetches this text from the `parameters.txt` file. It uses `:` as a delimiter for each line of the `parameters.txt` file and stores whatever is left of `:` in `var1` and whatever is right of `:` in `var2`. I want to print `matched` when `var1` stores `sheet_name` and `not matched` when it doesn't stores `sheet_name`. Following is my code which always prints `matched` irrespective of what `var1` stores:

```
filename=parameters.txt
IFS=$'\n'       # make newlines the only separator

for j in `cat $filename`
   do
      var1=${j%:*} # stores text before :
      var2=${j#*:} # stores text after :

      if [ “$var1” == “sheet_name” ]; then
         echo ‘matched’
      else
         echo “not matched“
      fi

done
```

What am I doing wrong? Kindly help.

Comment: Don't use a `for` loop here; read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: You should run your code through http://www.shellcheck.net to catch a few issues. Also read [Don't Read Lines with For](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) to see how to properly read line-by-line/field-by-field data.

Comment: Also your quotes are "smart"/unicode quotes and those aren't at all what you want in a shell script. Ensure you are using standard ASCII double and single quotes.

Comment: I just ran your script and sample file-- it works fine.  You shouldn't use a for loop, but it does work.  I have a feeling it's your parameters.txt that has an issue.  Do a `file parameters.txt` and see what the output is.

Comment: That would be just reading line by line. I need to extract the left side of `:` for each line too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have useless use of cat. But how about some [[ shell parameter expansion ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) ?

```
while read line
do
 if [[ "${line%:*}" = "sheet_name" ]] #double quote variables deals word splitting
 then
  echo "matched"
 fi
done<parameters.txt
```

would do exactly what you're looking for.

---

**Message for you**

[[ ShellCheck ]](http://shellcheck.net) says,

> "To read lines rather than words, pipe/redirect to a 'while read'
>   loop."

---

<sup>**Check [[ this ]](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2013) note from shellcheck.**</sup>

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
filename=parameters.txt

while IFS=: read -r first second; do 
  if [ “$first” == “sheet_name” ]; then 
     echo ‘matched’
  else  
     echo “not matched“ 
  fi 
done < $filename
```

Comment: Prints `not matched` for all cases.